# Tensorflow React Native Camera to both get predictions and record video?

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, expo

I have created my custom model and able to use it to get predictions from cameraWithTensors and in the document it says

> A higher-order-component (HOC) that augments the Expo.Camera component with the ability to yield tensors representing the camera stream.

So from my understanding we can both get predictions and record a video but is it possible to do that at the same time? For example if the prediction model detects red color on the screen, I'd like to stop recording video. Is this possible? Are there any code examples?

Comment: `cameraWithTensors` will always be processing the frames that is passed into it. What you intend to do is within the `handleCameraStream()` that is passed to it. From there you can just choose to stop recording(this depends on how you are recording the video) when you see the color red on the screen(not sure why red).

Comment: how about when to start the recording? I want to start after onPress function and automatically stop or show a warning on the screen like "warning: color is red". In which order startrecording, stoprecording and handlecamerastream should work?

Comment: Yeah shouldn't be an issue, real issue would be how to record the video and where are you storing the resulting video.

Comment: recordAsync gives a video uri. that should work? no? also in what order recording should start and stop without interrupting getting models for handlecamerastream? i'm confused because handleCameraStream starts with onReady prop and recordAsync starts with onPress